# What is the topology of teichmuller space of a given hyperhahler manifold

Tags: teichmuller-theory

From verbitsky's paper, I read that the teichmuller space of a given hyperkahler manifold is not hausdorff but it's smooth. I am a bit confused about how to put a natural topology on the teichmuller space.Any reference or simple example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one of the Verbitsky's paper are you talking about?